# Do Twig's logical operators evaluate both expressions?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

If I use a Twig expression like:

```
{% if a and function(a) %}
```

with `a` being falsey, does Twig still evaluate `function(a)`, or will the expression evaluate to `false` without evaluating the second part? Likewise with `or`.

Comment: I guess I could do that. I actually started looking at the source, since I couldn't find an answer online. However, I thought that perhaps someday a designer using twig might need to know, and might not know how to check themselves, so I thought I may as well ask, so that they could find help.

Comment: I hardly doubt *a designer* would care of that

Comment: Also, die's not a Twig function, so it's not as simple as that.

Comment: oh come on. Create your own function and call it http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#functions

Comment: Done and done. Hopefully this will be of use to someone some day.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

tl;dr: Twig's logical operators do not evaluate the second part of an 'and' expression if the first part is falsey, likewise with 'or' if the first part is truthy.

As [pointed out by zerkms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15606082/do-twigs-logical-operators-evaluate-both-expressions#comment22132687_15606082), this is testable by using die.

For example:

```
{% if water_is_dry and die('water_is_wet') %}
```

will not die, since the first expression, being null, is falsey.

Whereas:

```
{% if water_is_dry or die('water_is_wet') %}
```

will die.

Note, that this works only if you add die as a function to your Twig instance, like so:

```
$twig->addFunction(new Twig_SimpleFunction('die', 'die'));
```

Comment: @zerkms, I found this question and the new answer useful.  Maybe you should remove your minus here.