# Does Twig have short-circuit evaluation?

Tags: php, twig, conditional-statements, evaluation

[PHP has short-circuit evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694733/does-php-have-short-circuit-evaluation), such that `y` in `if x and y` is only evaluated if `x` is `true`. It seems likely that Twig, being built on PHP, would as well. Does it?

Edit: appreciate the "almost certainly the case for Twig" comments. Would love to hear from someone who can speak with certainty about Twig

Comment: Using AND/&&, if left-hand expression is `false` then right-hand expression will not be evaluated. At least in PHP and I assume twig.

Comment: No, if you use *and*, then the next statement will be evaluated only if previous is true. Thus you always put the most important first, like *isset* and then value check, etc.

Comment: Awesome thanks @Don'tPanic. Will update my question with that vocab

Comment: Sure, no problem

Comment: One more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15606082/do-twigs-logical-operators-evaluate-both-expressions?rq=1

Comment: @Don'tPanic ha I promise I did a bunch of searching first. Thanks

Comment: It's okay. I know how that goes.